Integral of Complex logarithm makes sense?
For example, I know that the principal branch of logarithm is not defined over negative real axis.
I think the integral of this logarithm along a circle doesn’t make sense.
Moreover, I know that the complex line integral is defined about (piecewise) continuous function on a given contour(piecewise smooth arc). However, log is not continuous on any circle.
How do I understand this situation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"...I know that the principal branch of logarithm is not defined over negative real axis" : this is wrong.  The principal branch of logarithm is defined on the negative real axis, but is (merely) not continuous on the negative real axis.  See the answer of Robert Israel.

The principal branch of the logarithm (let's call it $\text{Log}$) is continuous everywhere except on $(-\infty, 0]$: it takes a jump of $\pm 2\pi i$ as you cross the negative real axis.  There's no problem defining its integral around any circle, because we can integrate functions that are piecewise continuous with a finite number of jumps.  For example, if $C$ is the positively oriented unit circle, parametrized by $z = \exp(it)$, $t = -\pi \ldots \pi$,
$$ \oint_C \text{Log}(z)\; dz = \int_{-\pi}^\pi it (i \exp(it) \; dt) = -2\pi i$$

I appreciate it!

But that should be an improper integral right? since $Log \circ C$ evaluated in $t=-\pi$ or $t=\pi$ is not defined.

@FrancescoPeña-Garcia  Since changing a function at one point doesn't affect its integral, you can define the integrand to be continuous from the right at $t=-\pi$ and from the left at $t=+\pi$, and then there's nothing improper about the integral.
